Git push invalid username or password in VSCode
I use WSL with Ubuntu 20.04.6 and I use VSCode 1.91.1. I'm trying to authenticate with git push within my built-in VSCode terminal. Each time I try to do this, I am instantly hit with:
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'MY REPO'

but, outside of VSCode, within a regular WSL terminal, I am able to enter my username and token like normal.
I know that I need a personal access token. I have this. I am able to enter my username and token when I am outside of my VSCode instance.
My ~/.gitconfig file is empty, and my ~/.ssh/config file is empty. I just restarted my computer and the problem persists. This feels like there is some VSCode config file causing a problem that I am overlooking.
Any thoughts why the built-in VSCode terminal instantly fails authentication whereas a normal terminal outside of VSCode allows me to authenticate upon git push like normal?
Edit to add note: the VSCode terminal is running a WSL instance, and in the same directory.

You need to get together with the OP from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78801533/cant-remove-credentials-from-git-on-macososx who has exactly the opposite problem, VSCode is the only thing that does push successfully. Clearly VSCode stores its own GitHub authentication info somewhere.

@matt Thanks. I am going to remove and reinstall VSCode and report back if the problem still persists.

Back: reinstalling VSCode did nothing. Still can't push from VSCode terminal. And I can still successfully push from my WSL instance running within Windows Terminal.

Something fishy is going on here with VSCode. It's got to be some corrupted config somewhere.

I am more shocked that the terminal behavior in VSCode is different from the terminal behavior in Windows Terminal, both running WSL.

VSCode terminal has a lot of smarts to monitor what you run there and intercept things it can help with: if you run a command to open a port on the remote, it creates a tunnel for you automatically, and if you run a Git command in the terminal, it provides the credentials to connect to the Git server for you. Usually that's handy -- I especially like the auto-tunnel feature -- but sometimes it adds a layer of mystery to what's going on, and leads to different results connecting to a Git server from a regular terminal vs its own.
